# how to compare between two strings using recursion in C

Tags: c

i need to compre two strings and to compare them using recursion. in the process to count the number of the differences up to two.
i tried this:

```
int strcmp1(char *str1, char *str2){
int err=0;
if(strlen(str1)-strlen(str2)>1 ||strlen(str1)-strlen(str2)<1)
    return 0;

 if (*str1 =='\0' && *str2=='\0'|| err==2)
    return err;

if (*str1!=*str2)
    err++;

return strcmp1(str1 + 1, str2 + 1);
}
```

the code i wrote returns only 0 or 1, not the amount of differences...
can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?
thx :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question showing no effort to do the work. From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.* You've done neither of those things.

Comment: ok, i did a mistake. i hope that this is a better qustion... and this point and for the future i will add my ways of solving the problem

Comment: How do you define the number of differences? What's the number of differences between "tralfamador" and "ralfamador"?

Comment: if word1[i]!=word2[i], this is a difference. in your example the are 11 differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code contains several errors:

1. do not use `strcmp()` as a function name unless you really know what you do!  This function and its semantic is defined by the C standard. The compiler can rely on it and can replace calls with a more efficient implementation
2. `strlen(str1)-strlen(str2) > 1` is prone to (defined) unsigned integer underflows and will hold in most cases (e.g. `strlen("a") - strlen("aaaaaaa") > 1` is **true**).

   Use `strlen(str1) > strlen(str2) + 1` (usually you should check the `+ 1` operation for overflows too)
3. The modifications of `err` will never be seen by the recursive calls.  Either declare it as `static` or pass it as a paramter to your function.

Comment: thx for your explenations, they helped me alot, buti can't use static nor use err as a parameter... the function must be as it defined and without using static nor call another functions... i'm trying another way. if it will work i will post it...

Answer (score 0):

- when both strings are empty (*str == 0) return true
- when just one string is empty, return false
- if first chars are not same return false
- otherwise return the result of comparing the rest of the strings

I think you second if has some errors

Comment: and if i need the exact number of errors, and not thet there are?

Comment: the exact number is 1, you are check if they both are empty

Answer (score 0):

this is the final code i'v written...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int one(char* s1, char* s2){
  int two;
  if(*s1==' '){
      two=one(s1+1,s2);
      return two;
  }
  if(*s2==' '){
      two=one(s1,s2+1);
      return two;
     }
  if(*s1=='\0' && *s2=='\0'){
      return 0;
  }
    if(*s1=='\0'){
        return strlen(s2);
    }
  if(*s2=='\0'){
      return strlen(s1);
  }
  two=one(s1+1,s2+1);
  if (*s1==*s2){
return two;
}
    else{
        return two+1;
}
} 
void main(){
    int diff;
    char str1[51],str2[51];
printf("enter the first string\n");
    scanf("%s", &str1);
    printf("enter the second string\n");
    scanf("%s", &str2);
    diff=one(str1,str2);
    if(diff==1){
    printf("1\n");
}
    else{
        printf("0\n");
}
  }
```